# Meteor: Prevent undefined result for findOne()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to get some information out of a collection - in this example the user collection; but could be anything:

```
var result = Users.findOne({ _id: Meteor.userId() }).profile.anything;
```

In some cases the information is missing. For example if the DB is empty, I would get the error  `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`.

What would be the best way to prevent this if I'm using `findOne` and get an undefined result?

I would do something like:

```
var temp = Users.findOne({ _id: Meteor.userId() });
    if (temp) 
        var result = temp.profile.anything;
```

But that looks not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cover this in some detail in my post on [guards](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). This isn't really an issue with meteor or even the `find` operations - its just defensive programming in JavaScript. The generally accepted practice in cases where a guard may be needed is something like:

```
x && x.y && x.y.z
```

which covers the case where one or more of `x` and `y` are undefined.

You may run into situations where a long function is predicated on the existence of some piece of data. In those situations you may want to do something like:

```
user = Meteor.user();
if (!user) return;
...
// rest of function which assumes user is defined
```